# pointcloud_to_laserscan error on eddiebot stack

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everybody, I'm trying to run successfully the following launch file:
robotictang/eddiebot/blob/master/eddiebot/eddiebot_bringup/kinect.launch

> This code block was moved to the following github gist:
> https://gist.github.com/answers-se-migration-openrobotics/5005c79984aa828d9ab174a6b8195085

which is part of the eddiebot stack
it was created by Tang Tiong Yew to interface the Eddie robot with ROS using turtlebot API's

I installed the package point_cloud_to_laserscan and the error keeps apearing.

I saw that the use of this package was eliminated from the most recent turtlebot stack file.

they use insted "3d.sensor.launch" is there a way that I can use that file for this robot?

thank you,
Omar

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58386/pointcloud_to_laserscan-error-on-eddiebot-stack/) by [konet](https://answers.ros.org/users/4438/konet/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2013-03-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

thank you it worked,
here is my generic kinect.launch file

do I need to modify anything else?

---

Originally posted by [konet](https://answers.ros.org/users/4438/konet/) with karma: 16 on 2013-03-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jon Stephan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2281/jon-stephan/) on 2013-03-21**:
Apparently not, if it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I seem to remember having this problem, and I ended up using [depthimage_to_laserscan](http://www.ros.org/wiki/depthimage_to_laserscan).

My launch file ended up looking like this:

```
  <include file="$(find yertle)/launch/openni.launch"/> 
  <!-- fake laser -->
  <node machine="robot" pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="kinect_laser" args="load depthimage_to_laserscan/DepthImageToLaserScanNodelet camera_nodelet_manager">
    <param name="output_frame_id" value="/scanner"/>
    <remap from="image" to="/camera/depth/image_raw"/>
  </node>
```

-Jon

---

Originally posted by [Jon Stephan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2281/jon-stephan/) with karma: 837 on 2013-03-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2